# How to tell a language parser scanner that a string is a literal and not an identifier by looking at the previous token

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lexer

I'm writing a query language parser and I'm currently facing an issue that I have not seen in programming language compilers.

I have the following query:

`status=acknowledged`

And I'm expecting `status` to be a variable identifier and `acknowledged` to be a string literal. The only way to determine that is by looking at the `=` operator in between.

In theory the scanner should be able to return a new token without looking at the previous ones, but if that's the case, how would you distinguish an identifier from a string literal?
Bear in mind that I cannot just add double-quotes around the `acknowledged` string as I need to work with a query language that already exists and I'm not allowed to make any changes to it.

Should I just keep track of the previous N tokens inside the scanner and act accordingly?

Things get even messier if I have something like this:

`status=acknowledged&visibility=all`

In this case both `=` and `&` are operators so I can't just say that if the token before the one I'm currently parsing is an operator I should consider this as a string literal.

Comment: You either need explicit literals (i.e. wrapped in quotes, which you've stated you can't); or you need to keep track of the previous token(s); or you need a parser that operates as a state machine (i.e. it sees the `=` token and goes into "assignment value" state, treating the next token as a value literal).

Comment: @Adrian the parser I wrote actually already operates in a way that it takes into consideration unary and binary expressions and builds a tree out of that, but the scanner itself is agnostic from the parser, so maybe I should add a state machine to the scanner? Do you know of any documentation about such a scanner?

Comment: I'm sure there is some but a question like that is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you need to ask yourself is "Does my parser need to know whether `acknowledged` is a variable identifier or a string literal?"

And I'm going to venture to suggest that the answer is, "No, it doesn't". You can *parse* an expression like `status=acknowledged&visibility=all` without knowing anything about `status` and `acknowledged` (or `visibility` and `all`) other than that they are operands. A possible lexical category for such operands might be "bare words" (the term comes from Perl) or "atoms" (Lisp).

Of course, at some point you will want to figure out what these tokens *mean* (which is, by definition, a semantic question) and at that point some of them will be resolved to "variable name" and others to (unquoted) "string literal". If, for example, your `=` operator insists that its left-hand operand be a variable name and that its right-hand operator be a literal, you could easily do the appropriate transformations during a top-down traverse of the parse tree. I'm pretty sure that is the approach taken by most similar parsers.

By the principle of separation of concerns, each component in a language processor should restrict itself, as much as possible, to a single piece of the puzzle. Try to avoid the temptation to prematurely do analysis which could more comfortably be delayed to an appropriate future phase. You'll find that all of the logic is simpler if you work according to this pattern.